# Node as GCM client

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I need to test GCM communication as well as some other network related tasks. I would like to run a node.js script that would do some requests and (I hope it's possible) receive gcm messages as a GCM client i.e. identically like an Android app. I know I can have GCM client on Android, IOS, Chrome App, but are there any libraries for such a functionality on node? If not, how can I test multiple gcm clients without actually using Android?

Thank you for any responses!

Edit: one possible solution I see it's to user Chrome WebApp as a proxy between my node.js client and gcm server.

Comment: Currently there are GCM clients for Android, iOS and Chrome. There is no way to directly receive a GCM message in a node.js application.  I think you could use one of the supported platforms as a proxy like you stated.

Comment: Yes, Chrome extension proxy works like a charm. Thank you for your comment